# Processing complex data filters

Tags: database, filtering, relational-database, rdbms

I'm trying to figure out the best way to deal with the following situation.

Let's say we have an entity type with attributes A, B and C. Each of these attributes can have a known set of possible values. Entities have consumers that are only interested in entities with certain attribute values. This is defined using filters. For example (3 filters):

```
A   B   C

A1  B12 C4
A3  B2  - 
A11 -   C2
```

Ax, Bx and Cx are specific values, '-' means 'any value'. Filter values are AND'ed, multiple filters are OR'ed. The final combination would look like this:

```
(A=A1 AND B=B12 AND C=C4) OR (A=A3 AND B=B2) OR (A=A11 AND C=C2)
```

When an entity is saved into the database, I want to notify certain consumers about it. The consumers to be notified are those who have defined at least one filter that matches attribute values of the saved entity.

I'm expecting to have thousands of consumers, each of them with multiple filters defined. There will probably be ~30 attributes as well. The whole thing will use a relational database (MySQL).

The first thing that comes to mind is having some continuosly running process that periodically does entity searches for each consumer based on their defined filters and then notifies the consumer if new entities are found. This would work, but I'm not sure having thousands of somewhat complex queries running all the time is a good idea. Are there any less performance intensive alternatives, or is my concern about performance premature here?

Comment: Are you certain that you need to notify the consumers, rather than waiting for the consumers to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a binary key. If you take the example that you have above, if there are a limited number of options for A, B, and C then assign a value to each option and represent this as a binary value. Example there are options between 1 and 8 for A, B and C.  In a binary string a can then be any value form 000 to 111. The same can be said of options B and C.  Then by adding the numbers together you have one Key that can represent any option selected for options of A , B and C. Use either the first or last option to represent ALL (I.e no filter).

A sample key may then be 010  001 111 (010=A1; 001=B12; 111 = Any Option in C)

Converting the binary key to an integer value : E.g 010001111 = 143 as a decimal.

Then a SQL Query of SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerStoredFilterKEY IN (143, 155, 152)

Will return a result very quickly

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but if you do the single SELECT on insert, the number of binary keys would be very large if you have more than a few attributes: `1+2+3+...+n`, n is the number of attributes. For example, if you insert an entity `[1,5,2]`, you'll have to check for the following filters: `[1,5,2]`, `[1,5,-]`, `[-,5,2]`, `[1,-,-]`, `[-,5,-]`, `[-,-,2]`. If you have 30 attributes that would be 465 keys in a single SELECT statement.

Comment: The idea of a bianary key is that the one Key imbeds all of the possible options. Each space in the key is actually a switch to indicate the option has been selected or not selected.   So if there are 10 parameters your key will be 10 (binary) digits.

Comment: A key is a combination of attribute values expressed as a binary number and converted to a decimal number. For different value combinations there will be different keys. A key encodes a filter since filters are value combinations. Since many filters can match a particular entity, all possible filter keys will have to be used in your example SELECT statement to find all Customers that have any of the filters defined. In short, what I wrote in my previous comment still stands. It could be that I misunderstood you. In that case a more detailed example would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* high-level because I've never done anything like this before, and it depends a lot on what the other processes are, but off the top of my head...

You could have a trigger on insert call some code to write a message to a message queue which specifies what filter(s) the new record matches. Your consumers then get messages somehow from the queue, and find out about the inserted records they are interested in consuming. This removes the problem of having a process constantly querying and polling the table, but adds overhead to inserting into the table.

Comment: Finding out which filters the newly inserted entity matches would probably be way too costly to do on insert (checking the entity's attribute values against all defined filters).

Answer (score 0):

If you are building this query dynamically then the performance should be fine, assuming reasonable indexes.   After all, it will resolve to a single select statement for each query.

If it were me, I'd be more concerned about hardcoding each attribute as a table column.  You might want to consider making the attributes a child table -- but then, that *would* have a negative impact on performance.

I'm less sure about this, but I wonder if MySQL would handle those ORs better if they were done as seperate select statements that then went through a union.  Of course, you can test that with 'explain', etc.